# Node.js Websocket server won't work online

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket

I'm implementing a very simple Node.js Websocket server for a game in HTML5 + PHP. I tested my server locally and works fine, but when I deployed my server and client (in different domains, of course), I just can't connect them. 
I deployed the server at [https://evennode.com](http://evennode.com). I'm new to Node.js, maybe I'm missing something in my code.

```
var users = [];
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var connections = {};
var registered  = {}; 

var connectionIDCounter = 0;

var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: port}, function(){

    console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);

});

wss.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.id = connectionIDCounter ++;

    connections[socket.id] = socket;
    registered[socket.id] = 'Guest' + socket.id;

    connections[socket.id].position = {};
    connections[socket.id].position.x = 0;
    connections[socket.id].position.y = 1.8;
    connections[socket.id].position.z = 0;

    console.log('Connected: ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        var resultObject = JSON.parse(message);

        parseMessage(this.id, resultObject);        
    });

    socket.on('close', function(message) {
        sendUserState(this.id, 'disconnected'); 

        delete registered[this.id];
        delete connections[this.id];    

    });

});
```

I little help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it works locally, then clearly your code is fine.  If it doesn't work after you deploy it, its probably a firewall/configuration issue.

Comment: Why can't it connect?

Comment: This sounds like a CORS issue. What is your browser console output?

Comment: @VitaliyZurian http://enable-cors.org/ CORS issue.

Comment: Firefox show this error:
**Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en ws://jailhead.evennode.com/.** 
(Firefox cannot establish a connection with server at ws://jailhead.evennode.com)

Well, I put a test file at the same origin [link](http://jailhead.evennode.com) and it says the same error. Could it be a hosting problem?

Comment: Is there a way to test if the server is really up and listening?

Comment: Can you `"ping jailhead.evennode.com"` from the computer where your browser is?  Can you `"tracert jailhead.evennode.com"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosting at [www.evennode.com](http://www.evennode.com) uses Phusion Passenger to run Node.js apps which in turn uses [inverse port binding](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Node.js-tutorial#wiki-port_binding) (as mentioned e.g. [here by the author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645231/phusion-passenger-error-http-server-listen-was-called-more-than-once)) which makes this example not work when hosted by evennode.com.

There's a way though to make it work even with "inverse port binding" in place.
You first need to create an `http` server and then pass it to the `ws` constructor.

A simplified example below:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server}, function(){});

server.listen(3000);

wss.on('connection', function(socket) {
  ...
});
```

Hope this helps solve the issue.
Btw. there's also an [example with Socket.io](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-nodejs-websocket-demo) if anyone is interested.